# How do I replace only part of an image source?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there a way to use jQuery to change a part of an image's source URL?

I'm working on a page that has a number of image elements that are all programmatically generated (but I'm not able to access the source code that generates them). And they all share the same class.

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/01.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/02.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/03.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/04.jpg" class="photo">
```

Simple enough. But now, what if I want to point them all to a different directory? Like: /images/

So far, I've tried a few things, including this bit of jQuery, but nothing's done the trick so far:

```
$("img.photo").attr("src").replace("pictures","images");
```

That feels like it should do it because it's targeting images with that class -> then the "src" attribute -> and telling it to replace "pictures" with "images."

But I'm extremely new to using jQuery, so I'd appreciate some help.

What am I missing here? Any advice?

*UPDATE: Huge thanks to those who provided answers and explanations — I really appreciate you helping a beginner!*

Comment: `replace` requires you to assign the result.  So, get the `src` attribute, do the replace, and then assign the result back to the `src` attribute of the element.

Comment: (and you need to iterate over the collection when you do the assignment to each element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you simply change the returned string from
`$("img.photo").attr("src")` without doing anything with it afterwards. This will not change the attribute in your `<img>` elements.

This should do the job:

```
$("img.photo").each(function(){this.src=this.src.replace("pictures","images")})
```

Here I go through all the matched elements and assign the changed `src` string back to each element's `src`attribute.

```js
$("img.photo").each(function(){this.src=this.src.replace("pictures","images")});

// list the changed src values in the console:
console.log($("img.photo").map((i,img)=>img.src).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/01.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/02.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/03.jpg" class="photo">
<img src="https://cdn.example.com/pictures/04.jpg" class="photo">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet won't work, because that's grabbing the `src` attribute of the first image, and changing it, but never setting the result as the new `src` on the `<img>` elements.

Try this

```js
  $("img.photo").each((index, img) => {
    img.src = img.src.replace("pictures","images");
  });
```